# MOSFET goes into saturation mode much later

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, delay, nmos, saturation

I am using **IRLML6346 NMOS** in **LTSpice**. Its threshold voltage is **Vt = 0.95V**. I plotted the graph of **Vds**(voltage between drain and source) vs **Ids**(Current from drain to source) for different values of **Vgs**(Voltage between gate and source)

[image: Plot of Ids vs Vds for different Vgs]
I have written the gate voltage Vgs on the right below each plot and the approximate Vds value after which the NMOS goes into saturation mode.

For **Vgs = 4.5**, the saturation should start as soon as Vds >= Vgs - Vt. So it should go into saturation mode at **4.5 - 0.95 = 3.44**. But in the plot, it goes into saturation at **5.4 volts**.
Similarly, for **Vgs = 4**, the saturation should start at **4 - 0.95 = 3.05**, but it starts at **Vds = 4V**.

This same case happens for all the Vgs values. The saturation occurs much later. Why is this so?

[image: Mosfet Circuit it ltspice]

This is the circuit I have made.

Why does the MOSFET does not go into saturation mode as soon as Vds >= Vgs - Vt?

Comment: Models in SPICE, in general, are not always the best representatives to the real world case, where even there tolerances and whatnot come into play. Still, they try to be as close as they can. Some succeed, some don't. Welcome to the "real world" of the simulators, and congratulations for taking the first step before using a model: verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot about RdsOn * Ids.

Since Vds rises with Ids*RdsOn and Ids=Vds/RdsOn ,

I think linear Saturation is better defined as ;

\$V_{DS(sat)} >= V_{GS}  - V_t  + I_{DS}*R_{dsON}\$

You may sub RdsOn with another equation and reduce more.

**Then $$I_{DS(sat)}<= k V_{DS}^2$$**

[image] [REF](http://www.uta.edu/ronc/5342/lectures/L35_5342_Sp11.ppt)

Comment: I used this equation **VDS(sat)>=VGS−Vt+IDS∗RdsON** to find out RdsON at Vgs = 4.5 and Vt = 0.95(R comes out to be = **0.02196**). I used this R value for other Vgs values and I got Vds for saturation very close to the simulation values. So this works. Thanks.

But the MOSFET **IRLML6346 NMOS** model used has **Ron 0.048** ohms in ltspice.
Why is the calculated value different from the value I got. Any reason? Thank you.

Comment: Vt has a tolerance of 37.5% about 0.8V yet Ron is 46 mΩ typ and 63 mΩ max @ 4.5V, Id=3.4A for Vds*Id(Ron)=63mΩ*3.4A=214mV max rise so I'm not sure.  Maybe worst case? Vt=1.1